Which French-language prayer times site is most relevant
I would like to know which site indicating prayer times is the most relevant, I live in France and I am currently consulting the site https://heure-priere.fr/

Attention, ce site est en langue anglaise. J'ai pris la liberté de traduire votre question, mais les réponses seront en anglais aussi.

In order to answer this we need to know what is the basis of the prayer time tables. In most cases one can get a prayer sheet from the next mosque and rely on it.
